# Migrating RAID-0 array from internal to dedicated controller

Tags: raid, raid-0

I've got a ASUS Z77 motherboard with 6 internal SATAIII connectors. I'd like to set up an array of up to 4 SSDs in RAID0, but before I do that, I'd like to know if it's easily possible to migrate the array to a dedicated RAID card. I've heard that some controllers layout drives for certain RAID levels in different ways, so I'd like to make sure that I have a fairly seamless transition between the motherboard RAID controller to the dedicated RAID controller.

Comment: You make a backup, and then you restore the backup.  If you are running RAID0, you better already have a great backup system in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ghost/image your 4-drive RAID0 array to a single drive. Then, move your four drives over to the dedicated controller.

If the transfer fails for whatever reason, you can then ghost your single drive back to the array. No risk of losing data.

However, I highly advise you against a 4-drive RAID0 array. You do realize that the performance gain from two to four drive is marginal at best and if a single drive encounters any kind of failure you lose the entire array and all the data with it.

Comment: "The 0 and 1 in RAID 1 or RAID 0 is how many drives can fail without the entire array dying" - Anonymous

Comment: Haha awesome quote!

Comment: I know what I'm getting myself into, that's why I'm going to be running a RAID-5 or RAID-6 dedicated backup array of the main drives. 4 SSDs in RAID-0 should give me some pretty ridiculous speed, and that's what I'm after.

Comment: **TL;DR** You should make a backup because it may or may not work.